# shell_exec doesn't work on Linux server

Tags: php, linux, server, exec, shell-exec

I'm using youtube-dl.exe on my Windows WAMP server and `shell_exec()` is working great on Windows, I get the right info from youtube-dl (returns a string).

Once the same PHP script is uploaded on my real Linux server it just stops working, even though I upload the Linux version of youtube-dl.

for the Linux version file that I've obtained from a sudo curl command on a Linux machine on VirtualBox, I'm trying to do this:

```
$var = shell_exec("youtube-dl -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97Eagwlt-ZA");
```

And for the same version I've got on my WAMP server (exe):

```
$var = shell_exec("youtube-dl.exe -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97Eagwlt-ZA");
```

Both of the commands returns absolutely nothing, the two different version of files are in the same root (/) folder and

```
$var = exec("youtube-dl -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97Eagwlt-ZA", $errors);
```

`$errors` returns an empty Array()

But

```
$var = shell_exec("echo test > test.txt");
```

Works like a charm (creates the test file with "test" inside of it).

The PHP & youtube-dl files' CHMOD is set to 755. PHP Version 5.6.
I'm really stuck here.. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your youtube-dl? Maybe try `shell_exec("./youtube-dl -g ......");` ?

Comment: All of the files are placed in the root (/) folder, here's a screen of FileZilla: https://i.imgur.com/ZixIaTy.jpg, the CHMOD is set to 755. I must admit I'm pretty lost right now.

Comment: UPDATE: After hours and hours of tricking, I think I found where the problem is: the youtube-dl needs ressources that are installed by sudo apt install. Problem is that I can't execute that command even though I'm on a private server, the terminal throws me something like you're not in sudoers group. The grep -Po command returns nothing (no sudoers on my server)... I feel like I just need to find a way to execute the "sudo apt install youtube-dl" command and then on my PHP side I'll be calling it like shell_exec("youtube-dl -g etc")!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Check to make sure youtube-dl has execute permissions for the webserver user. On Linux systems scripts have to be flagged executable in order to be run directly. Setting 755 permissions should do the trick.
- Either add ./ to the path (e.g. ./youtube-dl) or make sure youtube-dl is on the web server's $PATH. Unlike Windows the current directory isn't automatically included on the path.
- If your Linux server is running SELinux or AppArmor these applications may be preventing your web server from running commands. You can generally find out about items getting blocked in your syslog.

Comment: Thx for your answ. 1. File permissions seems to be OK (screen of FileZilla: https://i.imgur.com/ZixIaTy.jpg) 2. $_SERVER["PATH"] is /bin:/usr/bin  I've tried system("ls") to see what's the actual execution folder, it shows me the root (/) folder where my youtube-dl, php etc. files are. I'm not as comfortable on Linux as on Windows so I don't really understand the UNIX structure of folders but here's how far I can go on the root of the server it self: https://i.imgur.com/eFzqaEx.jpg
3. I've contacted my hoster to ask, because the logs shows nothing...